# An app that automatically sends messages and makes calls to emergency contact

Tags: java, android

I am totally new to Android, and Java. I am designing an app that is constantly getting some input data(vital signals) and once abnormal reading is observed, ie heart rate < 50, the app will automatically send messages and make calls to one (or many) emergency contact(s). The tutorials I have found so far mentioning "auto send/call" are all about sending/calling within our own app using Intent, but the user still has to press the button to continue. Is there any way to do that?
The one I have now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText phone;
    private ImageButton call;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        phone = findViewById(R.id.number);
        call = findViewById(R.id.call);

        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        //set number
            public void onClick(View v){
                String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });




    }
}
```

I have tried removing the listener so that it no longer waits for me to click the button to call:

```
 phone = findViewById(R.id.number);
 //Removed listener
 String phoneNumber = phone.getText().toString();
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
 startActivity(intent);
```

But it turns out that once I launch the app, the app makes call directly even without typing in the number and of course call fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a Trigger Event. You can check this site for more information about it.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/TriggerEvent

Comment: Since my plan is the app needs to be monitoring all the times and might make multiple calls, is it possible to place the trigger event in a while loop?

Comment: I don't think you need to use a while loop. The `TriggerEventListener` will do the job.

Comment: The page says "This class is the listener used to handle Trigger Sensors. Trigger Sensors are sensors that trigger an event and are automatically disabled." I want the sensors to continue working even after an event is triggered.